# Stop phpstorm from completing `<?php` with `?>`

Tags: phpstorm

Every time I press enter when the caret is at the end of `<?php`, phpstorm adds `?>` after the tag.

I've been looking for and turning off every "auto completion" or "close tag" setting I can find, but still my code gets overrun by extra `?>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [vote for the open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7230) about this problem in YouTrack.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know its a known issue. I was going crazy trying to search for <?php